# Getting 404 , URL not found while running Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, langchain

I am new to Python and while running the flask server for a QA module using huggingface I am getting 404 url not found error everytime.
Here is the complete code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter 
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings 
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
import json
from langchain import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator 
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter 
import os
# Set the Hugging Face API token as an environment variable
os.environ["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"] = "###" (removing the token here)
# Pre-load necessary components (assuming model and data are static)
# Load the PDF (replace path with your actual file location)
loader = PyPDFLoader("C:/Users/abhishek.m19/Desktop/grimm_hanse_and_gretel.pdf")
pages = loader.load_and_split()

# Define parameters for text chunking
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
  chunk_size=1024,
  chunk_overlap=64,
  separators=['\n\n', '\n', '(?=>\. )', ' ', '']
)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(pages)

# Create word embeddings for the text chunks
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
# Build a FAISS vector store to index the embeddings for fast retrieval
db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)

# Load the FLAN-T5 large language model from Hugging Face Hub
llm=HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="google/flan-t5-base", model_kwargs={"temperature":1, "max_length":1000000})

# Load a LangChain question-answering chain for processing
chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")

# Create a Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
print("Flask running\n")
# Define an API route to handle user queries
@app.route("/home", methods=["POST"])
def answer_question():
  # Get the user question from the request body
  print("entering the function\n")
  data = request.get_json()
  print("data= ", data)
  if not data or "user_question" not in data:
    return jsonify({"error": "Missing user_question in request body"}), 400
  question = data["user_question"]
  print("Question is ", question)

  # Perform similarity search in the vector store to find relevant document chunks
  docs = db.similarity_search(question)
  print("Docs= ", docs)

  # Run the question-answering chain to generate an answer
  result = chain.run(input_documents=docs, question=question)
  print("result is ", result)

  # Return the generated answer as JSON
  return jsonify({"answer": result})

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

What is the error that I have done in the code can anyone please help me out?

I have tried debugging the code in vscode but not able to find the error/solution.

Comment: Which URL are you trying to access ? Note that it should be /home

Comment: "Here is the complete code:": instead, please reduce your code to the absolute necessary to reproduce your problem. Everything langchain related seems to be unnecessary noise when it comes to Flask and getting a 404.

Comment: @Nifil I am trying to access http://127.0.0.1:5000

Comment: Ok so what about accessing 127.0.0.1:5000/home ?

Comment: @Nifil its the same

Comment: @Abhishek Mohapatra Try to change @app.route("/home", methods=["POST"]) to
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"]) and access 127.0.0.1:5000 it should work

Comment: @AbhishekMohapatra is your endpoint is expecting a POST request to `/home`, a GET request to `/` will not work.